# set LayOut Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to add Layout Dynamically on Add button click and on Dynamic Layout show Datepicker,Timepicker Dialog and set value in given Edit Text. show in image on Date Click set Date Right side . Here problem Start when Add Second  Same layout and set date it set only on newly created layout

[image: i]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you facing any problem ? or you want code from scratch ?

Comment: Here problem Start when Add Second Same layout and set date it set only on newly created layout

Comment: please clarify....i didnt get what you wrote.

Comment: i inflate layout by View viewmain;
   viewmain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relative, null);
   LinearLayout r = (LinearLayout) viewmain.findViewById(R.id.linmain);
   lLayout.addView(viewmain);

Comment: but inflated layout's id of TextView and EditText  not get.

Comment: Hello @shivang ..whats your problem? can you explain your problem?

Comment: When you are creating view give it id too. So you can identify click of every view.....

Comment: List-view will be somehow complex in your case but it will work efficiently in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you need to create xml layout file with ScrollView and LinearView inside.
Then in your Activity class:

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
   setContentView(main);

   LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)main.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

and then in onClick method just:

```
View yourView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourView, null);
// Do whatever you want with your View, set up some variables etc.
```

and to add your view to main view:

```
linear.addView(yourView);
```

I know that this is not a direct answer to your question, but maybe will help you with dynamically adding Views.

Comment: ya it's fine.but how to set onclick on newly created Layout's TextView. or Show Datepicker on TextView and set Date its Right side

Comment: you added new View from xml file. So just create layouts as xmls file, depends what you need. Before add view you can setup it with your data.

Comment: pls see images and tell me how can open Dialog on each layouts